# mysql update, replace spaces and limit

Tags: mysql

I have now this

```
en_title cell
huawei e160e best modem for mobile using, 3g hsdpa



UPDATE lang_temp
SET fi_content = CONCAT( '<a href="http://www.google.fi/search?hl=fi&source=hp&q=', en_title ,'&meta=&aq=f&oqnofollow" target=_blank>Google search...</a>')
WHERE en_content ='';
```

I need to replace spaces to + charters and limit to 15 charters the value.

In result i need to get

```
<a href="http://www.google.fi/search?hl=fi&source=hp&q=huawei+e160e+best+f&meta=&aq=f&oqnofollow" target=_blank>Google search...</a>
```

How it possible?

Comment: sql has REPLACE, SUBSTR and TRIM functions

Comment: i have tryed them, but how i can get it all in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use str_replace(" ","+","YOUR URL"); for replacing spaces with + in the given URL

Comment: how it can be combined with 15 charter limitation?